# Django - How to grant custom permissions to some users in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to grant some users retrieve access, some users update access and no retrieve/update access for unauthenticated users to my DRF API.
In my extended user model, I have two fields that defines whether a user should be allowed Retrieve or Update to the API.  How should I write the logic in my DRF custom permissions class to check these two fields and grant retrieve or update depending if True or False? Should I use a ViewSet for this or use separate ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView and UpdateAPIView classes with Mixins? What is the best way to do this?

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    allowRetrieveAPI = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
    allowUpdateAPI = models.BooleanField(default=False,)

class Track(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Submitted by", default=1)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
```

views.py

```
class CheckAPIPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    # allow retrieve if userprofile.allowReadAPI is True
    # allow update if user userprofile.allowUpdateAPI is True  

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
         # return something
    def check_object_permission(self, user, obj):
         # return something      
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
         # return something

class TrackViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Track.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer
    permission_classes = (CheckAPIPermissions,)
```

Comment: Every one can access the list method, then?

Comment: I forgot that, but if they are able to retrieve, they should be allowed the list method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CheckAPIPermissions(permissions.BasePermission): 
    # allow retrieve if userprofile.allowReadAPI is True 
    # allow update if user userprofile.allowUpdateAPI is True 

    def has_permission(self, request, view): 
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        elif request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            if (request.user.userprofile.allowRetrieveAPI or request.user.userprofile.allowUpdateAPI) and view.action == 'retrieve':
                return True
            elif request.user.userprofile.allowUpdateAPI and view.action == 'update':
                return True
        return False

    def check_object_permission(self, user, obj): 
        return (user and user.is_authenticated() and (user.is_staff or obj == user)) 


    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj): 
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        elif request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            if (request.user.userprofile.allowRetrieveAPI or request.user.userprofile.allowUpdateAPI) and view.action == 'retrieve':
                return request.user == obj
            elif request.user.userprofile.allowUpdateAPI and view.action == 'update':
                return request.user == obj
        return False
```

I haven't tested it, wrote just in a nick of time.